# Why divs are overlapping when browser is shrinked even when i set widths in percentage?

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have divided the screen in two `div`s with 40% and 59% widths but whenever i am shrinking my browser the second div overlaps the first div. Where am i going wrong?

```
#watch-container{
    width: 40%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
}
#watch-container .watch-skin{
    height: 60%;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 110px;
}

#desc-container{
    width: 59%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#content-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}
```

You can run the code below, or take a look at the codepen - https://codepen.io/tsiruot/pen/GRZMqZY

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{
    background-color: #233D53;
    height: 60px;
}

nav #logo{
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#watch-container{
    width: 40%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
}
#watch-container .watch-skin{
    height: 60%;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 110px;
}

#desc-container{
    width: 59%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#content-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}

#desc-container h1{
    padding-top: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 1000;
}
#color-header{
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
#desc-container p:nth-child(2){
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    font-weight: 500;
}
#desc-container h3{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#color-container button{
    height: 33px;
    width: 45px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
#color-container button:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#23211f ;
}
#color-container button:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #ca3d22;
}
#color-container button:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #565681;
}
#color-container button:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #8a5362;
}

#desc-container > button:last-child{
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(218, 131, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#desc-container > button:nth-last-child(3)
{
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#desc-container > button:nth-last-child(4)
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav>
            <img id="logo" src="amazon-img.png" alt="Amazon-logo" />
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="watch-container">
            <img class="watch-skin" src="https://i.imgur.com/iOeUBV7.png" alt="Black-strap" />
        </div>
        <div id="desc-container">
            <h1>FitBit 20 - The Smartest Watch</h1>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                 Asperiores nisi quae dolorem eaque porro itaque architecto et dolores dolorum natus.</p>
            <br />
            <p id="color-header"><b>Select Color</b></p>
            <div id="color-container">
                <button class="color"></button>
                <button class="color"></button>
                <button class="color"></button>
                <button class="color"></button>
            </div>   
            <br />
            <h3>Features</h3> 
            <button >Time</button>
            <button >Heart Rate</button>
            <br />
            <button>BUY NOW</button>
         </div>
        </div> 
    </section>
```

Comment: I think it is because you have specified the height of the div elements. by specifying the height, the text inside the second div does not get enough space, so it just overlaps the first div. You can try writing Overflow-y:auto in your second div style tag. I think it will do the trick or you can just remove the height tag.

Comment: Use bootstrap css instead, the responsive is already handled in bootstrap. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: @Purushothaman Bootstrap might work, but not everyone can (or wants to) use it. There are other responsive frameworks, or users might prefer a lightweight solution, or to do it themselves for more control. Recommendations for a framework are a matter of opinion, and in this case it's not a suitable answer - it would be overkill to change their entire site to work with Bootstrap just to fix this one problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the containers to percentage width, but the content of the 'watch-container' div is not responsive so it is overflowing its container as the container gets smaller.

This is what you are using:

```
#watch-container .watch-skin{
    height: 60%;
    margin-left: 170px;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

Between the width of the image and the left margin, the contents is over 500px regardless of what size the container is.

You need to remove the margin (use margin:auto to center the image if you want). You also need to make the image responsive based on *width* not *height*:

```
#watch-container .watch-skin{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

**Working Example**: This is your working code with responsive content for `#watch-container` - note the image is going to get very small when it has to fit in 40% of the screen. It would help if you didn't have the white space around the watch in the image:

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{
    background-color: #233D53;
    height: 60px;
}

nav #logo{
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 45px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

#watch-container{
    width: 40%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: inline-block;
}
#watch-container .watch-skin{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 110px;
}

#desc-container{
    width: 59%;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#content-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
}

#desc-container h1{
    padding-top: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 1000;
}
#color-header{
    font-size: 18px;
    
}
#desc-container p:nth-child(2){
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    font-weight: 500;
}
#desc-container h3{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#color-container button{
    height: 33px;
    width: 45px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
#color-container button:nth-child(1){
    background-color:#23211f ;
}
#color-container button:nth-child(2){
    background-color: #ca3d22;
}
#color-container button:nth-child(3){
    background-color: #565681;
}
#color-container button:nth-child(4){
    background-color: #8a5362;
}

#desc-container > button:last-child{
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
    width: 120px;
    height: 40px;
    outline: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(218, 131, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: 700;
}

#desc-container > button:nth-last-child(3)
{
    width: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
#desc-container > button:nth-last-child(4)
{
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<header>
        <nav>
            <img id="logo" src="amazon-img.png" alt="Amazon-logo" />
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="watch-container">
            <img class="watch-skin" src="https://i.imgur.com/iOeUBV7.png" alt="Black-strap" />
        </div>
        <div id="desc-container">
            <h1>FitBit 20 - The Smartest Watch</h1>
            <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
                 Asperiores nisi quae dolorem eaque porro itaque architecto et dolores dolorum natus.</p>
            <br />
            <p id="color-header"><b>Select Color</b></p>
            <div id="color-container">
                <button class="color"></button>
                <button class="color"></button>
                <button class="color"></button>
                <button class="color"></button>
            </div>   
            <br />
            <h3>Features</h3> 
            <button >Time</button>
            <button >Heart Rate</button>
            <br />
            <button>BUY NOW</button>
         </div>
        </div> 
    </section>
```

Comment: Keeping the width at 100% is making the watch look really big, i guess it has something to do with my image. I just can't keep the ratios of image right along with responsiveness.

Comment: @Tsiruot That's why responsive design can be so complicated :) It is showing really big because your image *is* really big. You can use a smaller image, or you can set a max-width for your watch image e.g. `max-width: 400px`. Also, because your image has white space to the left and right of the watch, this is also taking up space when the screen is made smaller. This is why elements are usually displayed as columns on small screens, so that the content isn't squished into half the screen and the images get too small and the text too long.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the divs are not getting overlapped. The image inside `#watch-container .watch-skin` contains a `margin-left` of `170px` this causes the image move out of its container Remove that value, your screen will be working as expected.

```
#watch-container .watch-skin{
    height: 60%;
    /* Remove this one */
    /* margin-left: 170px; */
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

If you are interested, you could go for a `display: flex` implementation in `css`. Only you have to change is the one mentioned below.

```
#content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#watch-container .watch-skin {
  height: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 110px;
}
```

This will give automatic `marin-left` with respect to your available space for the image.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: #233D53;
  height: 60px;
}

nav #logo {
  height: 40px;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

#watch-container {
  width: 40%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;  
}

#watch-container .watch-skin {
  height: 60%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 110px;
}

#desc-container {
  width: 59%;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

#desc-container h1 {
  padding-top: 140px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 1000;
}

#color-header {
  font-size: 18px;

}

#desc-container p:nth-child(2) {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 70%;
  font-weight: 500;
}

#desc-container h3 {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#color-container button {
  height: 33px;
  width: 45px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

#color-container button:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: #23211f;
}

#color-container button:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #ca3d22;
}

#color-container button:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: #565681;
}

#color-container button:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: #8a5362;
}

#desc-container>button:last-child {
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 153, 0);
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(218, 131, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#desc-container>button:nth-last-child(3) {
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#desc-container>button:nth-last-child(4) {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221);
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <img id="logo" src="amazon-img.png" alt="Amazon-logo" />
  </nav>
</header>
<section>
  <div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="watch-container">
      <img class="watch-skin" src="https://i.imgur.com/iOeUBV7.png" alt="Black-strap" />
    </div>
    <div id="desc-container">
      <h1>FitBit 20 - The Smartest Watch</h1>
      <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Asperiores nisi quae dolorem eaque porro itaque architecto et dolores dolorum natus.</p>
      <br />
      <p id="color-header"><b>Select Color</b></p>
      <div id="color-container">
        <button class="color"></button>
        <button class="color"></button>
        <button class="color"></button>
        <button class="color"></button>
      </div>
      <br />
      <h3>Features</h3>
      <button>Time</button>
      <button>Heart Rate</button>
      <br />
      <button>BUY NOW</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I think it was more of a height problem as pointed out by FluffyKitten. But i appreciate the margin-left: auto suggeston :)

Comment: @Tsiruot height or width is your option. You could either set the height or width of the image. Bothe doesnt have anything to do with your issue. Your core issue was the image poping out of the container.

Comment: @Tsiruot Your issue was the hardcoded value for margin-left

Answer (score 0):

I seen code.html structure is good but some problem in CSS properties. if you want left images in center of left box, you can apply below code to resolve your problem in all screen.

```
#watch-container .watch-skin{
    height: 60%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:block;
    margin-top: 110px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a fancy answer, but the problem is/are them `height: 100vh;` remove them. Instead use

```
..... {
  height:100%;
  min-height:100vh;
}
```